# Storing Zend subclasses

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my Zend folder structure, where should I keep classes that inherit or subclass Zend classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to create an own folder in the Library folder like 'App' or your project name, this will be your name space too.

```
Library
|
-- App
-- Zend
-- ...
```

Then you'll need to add to the application.ini the following for autoloading your namespace:

```
autoloadernamespaces.app = "App_"
```

Answer (score 2):

library-Zend
       -Your Library

And do not forget to add namespace for autoloading.